# Fitting an functional autoregressive model in R with mgcv

Tags: r, nonparametric, mgcv, functional-data-analysis

I'm working with the 'mgcv' package in R and I just want to know if I am going about the right way of fitting a functional autoregressive (FAR) model. The FAR model is represented as
$$Y=f_1(x.1)x.1+f_2(x.1)x.2$$

For the case of my data, I am using the `gam` function in R from the `mgcv` package where $x.1$ and $x.2$ are two columns of values that make up $Y$. Additionally, from the model above $f_1(x.1), f_2(x.1)$ are unknown smooth functions.  So I have defined my model in the following way,

```r
test <- gam(y~ s(x.1, by=x.1) + s(x.1, by=x.2),  
            data=test_data)
```

Where `test_data` is a data table containing the columns of $Y,x.1,x.2$. So my question is, is my setup correct with the `gam` function by using the `by` argument with the `s()` function as my FAR model is meant to be nonparametric.

Comment: Hmm... I can't see why this would be immediately correct. Do you have a reference you followed? If yes, can you please link it?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update this question. After doing some more digging around, I discovered that the FAR model I have listed above along with the gam function is indeed how it would be represented in R. Below is a reference from a link that details the mgcv package with the following,

"As an example, consider the model

$E(y_i) = b_0 + f(x_i)z_i$

where f is a smooth function, and $z_i$ is a numeric variable. The appropriate formula is:
`y ~ s(x,by=z)`

- the by argument ensures that the smooth function gets multiplied by covariate z. Note that when using factor by variables, centering constraints are applied to the smooths, which usually means that the by variable should be included as a parametric term, as well. "

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/gam.models.html

Comment: The model described does *not* have something to do with auto-regression. Ignore the functional part of a moment, an auto-regressive model needs something like $E(y_t)= \dots + y_{t-j} + \dots$. This ain't here, what is presented is a simple GAM (with some interactions...). Best case scenario for some auto-regression claims to be valid in such a model is if we assume we have an AR-structure in our error term bu then again, this is not presented here. (cont.)

Comment: See for example: the paper [Using a generalized additive model with autoregressive terms to study the effects of daily temperature on mortality](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-12-165) (2012) by Yang et al. they care for a Poisson response but ignoring that momentarily and looking at the explanatory variable we see how they *clearly* have $y_{t-j}$ terms.